# Derive expressions for $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ for $0 ≤ z ≤ 1.$ using d'Alembert's formula

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, wave-equation

Let $u(x, t)$ be the displacement of a string, at position $x$ and time $t$, which is stretched between two fixed points at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Its motion satisfies the wave equation, $$u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}\qquad x ∈ (0, 1),\: t > 0$$

where $c$ is a real positive constant, and is subject to boundary conditions
$$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 \qquad t > 0$$

The string has an initial displacement $u(x, 0) = f(x), x ∈ (0, 1)$ and is initially at rest.

Starting with the general solution to the wave equation
$$u(x, t) = h_1(x − ct) + h_2(x + ct)$$

for arbitrary functions $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$,

Derive expressions for $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ for $0 ≤ z ≤ 1.$

I understand d'Alemberts formula but Im getting confused when inputting my initial conditions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$ u(x,t) = h_1(x-ct) + h_2(x+ct), \\
u_t(x,t) = c( -h_1(x-ct)+h_2(x+ct) ). $$
The initial conditions tell you that for $0<x<1$,
$$ u(x,0) = f(x), \\
u_t(x,0) = 0. $$
Substituting the d'Alembert solution in,
$$ h_1(x)+h_2(x)=f(x) \\
-h_1(x)+h_2(x)=0, $$
so we find
$$ h_1(x) = h_2(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(x). $$

The boundary conditions are in a sense a red herring for this: what they tell you is what happens when $x \pm ct$ crosses the boundary, namely
$$ h_1(-ct)+h_2(ct) = 0, \\
h_1(1-ct)+h_2(1+ct) = 0, $$
and with these, we can extend the definitions of $h_1$ and $h_2$ to other $z$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Im also confused at any question which leads on from this.  By substituting in the boundary condition at $x = 0$ into the general solution derive an expression for $h_1(z)$ in terms of $h_2$ for $z < 0.$ Im not too sure but would the answer be: $h_1(z) = −h_2(−z).$ Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that works up to $z=-1$ (then one would have to use the other boundary condition, and so on).

Comment: Also, sorry for being a nuisance, but on the other side of the spectrum when you input the boundary condition $x=1$, Im not too sure what the expression for $h_2$ would be in terms of $h_1$ when $z>1.$ Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You get $h_2(1+z)=-h_1(1-z)$ from my last displayed equation.

Comment: How would I convert $h_2(1+z)$ into $h_2(z)$??

Comment: In general, you can't. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251752/221811) for how to do the periodicity.